# change asp.net panel rendered tag from div to span

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `<asp:Panel>` inside an `li`, so the problem is the html will not validate.

Any help in changing the rendered `div` to a `span`?

I'm doing this in a ASP.NET 4.0 website using c# code.

Comment: What do you _do_ with the panel? Can't it just be defined as a `<span>`?

Comment: What you want to achieved from span tag?

Comment: It shouldn't cause you problems.... can you add in the code and html output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look onto the Eilon Lipton's article [Customizing the rendering of the UpdatePanel](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2006/12/06/customizing-the-rendering-of-the-updatepanel.aspx).

He shows how to extend update panel with css class and custom tag properties in it.

Comment: It's an asp:Panel, not an UpdatePanel.

Comment: @PHeiber: yep, but the idea is the same, I posted a link to example only.

Comment: That would remove the OP's wish to use the DefaultButton behaviour from the Panel (although the OP didn't state that wish in the post). Granted you could add that code for that behaviour manually in the render children method.

Comment: +1 since it solves the stated question and is the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

Use a Label control; this equates to a span.  You cannot change what the panel renders as.

Comment: i have defaultbutton assigned on the panel

Comment: Yes, that won't translate over.  Also, just thought of something, if you want the DIV to act like an span layout, you could add: style="display:inline;".  You may be able to achieve what you want with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

It IS possible to change the rendering of a Panel from a div to a span: you could create a [Control Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67276kc5.aspx) that would override the default rendering of the Panel. You can read up on them and see some examples [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160919082842/http://www.singingeels.com:80/Articles/How_To_Control_Adapters.aspx) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150205091407/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx).

However, **I think I'd find another option for solving your problem**. Changing the behavior of a standard control like this might make it difficult for future developers to understand what's going on in your app. And the effort to get this working may be more than just using one of the other solutions! I can only see this as reasonable if you have a lot of pages with Panels already on them and you are unable/unwilling to change them all to some other mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Add javascript in order to enforce your default button behaviour for the contents of the panel and replace the panel with a plain `<span>` element.

If you are using jQuery, there are a couple of examples available [here](http://greatwebguy.com/programming/dom/default-html-button-submit-on-enter-with-jquery/) (check the comments as well).

Comment: -1: Security through obscurity comes to mind in a very abstract fashion here, in terms of offering an idea which makes the OP _believe_ they have a solution only to find as many caveats in time to come, but now they have different view controllers!

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: I fail to see how the responsibilty to tell which button to click as default upon pressing enter inside a field is that of a controller. That depends entirely on the implementation of the view IMO. Am I missing your point?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the tag for styling just add `display:inline` to your `div`. It would act as an `span`

Comment: It will still act as a div in IE7 :)